# Alternative of MultiThreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question bother me a while.
For example,I have a multithreaded server, when it receives a request, it pass this request to a handler, this handler will process this request. One reason we make server multithreaded is:
if it is not multithreaded, when the server processing this request, during the meaning time, 
another request coming, then this request will be drop, because the server is not available now.

So I wonder if there is an alternative of multithreaded server, for example, we can create a queue for non-multithreading server? when it can fetch another request from the queue once it finish one.

Comment: If the requestor does not need a synchronized reply, just implement a basic messaging queing service.  The component that receives the network connections still has to be multi-threaded, but it just slurps up the request data and dumps it into the (FIFO) queue.  You have single reader thread to take the oldest message off the queue for actual processing.  This kind of model has been used for many years and is common for point-to-point messaging systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still have a single threaded engine with a multi-threaded server.

consider the following skeleton - if you have an Engine that runs, it can be completely single threaded, just handing requests in the order they're received. This allows you to use non-thread-safe components in the business logic, and you've managed to separate your networking layer from your business logic layer! It's a win-win scenario.

```
class Engine implements Runnable {

    private final Object requestLock = new Object();
    private List<Request> requests = new LinkedList<Request>();
    private boolean running = true;

    private Request nextRequest() {
        synchronized(requestLock) { return requests.poll(); }
    }

    /**
     * The engine is single threaded. It doesn't care about server connections
     */
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            Request request = nextRequest();
            // handle your request as normal
            // also consider making a mechanism to send Responses
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have an [event-based server](http://oatv.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/01/nio.html). This capability is offered by the `java.nio` package, though you could use a framework like [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) rather than do it from scratch.

However, note that while this used to be considered a way to get better performance, it seems like a regular multithreaded server actually [offers better performances](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/java-io-faster-than-nio-old-is-new-again/) with today's hardware and operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Have you considered [SEDA-like](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/proj/seda/) techniques (i.e. [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) techniques)? You may want to investigate the [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) library too. It does most of the job for you when it comes to using NIO.